# How am I able to store a value without using cin, getline etc

Tags: c++, cin

I am stumped about this. So I wrote some code to try to explain it. I was wondering why I am able to store numbers or characters even though I have not prompted input with `cin` or `getline`? The only thing I can think of right now with my limited knowledge is "while (`!(cin >> num1)`)" but then again, why would a while loop execute the condition?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    while (!(cin >> num1))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input. Try again: ";
    }
}
```

Comment: A while loop always executes the code in its parentheses at least once... otherwise it wouldn't know whether or not to enter the body of the loop.

Comment: What would you expect the `while` loop to do other than execute the condition? Can you think of a reason to write a `while` loop that did *not* execute the condition at least once to decide whether it needed to execute the code in the loop or not?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, I always just thought that 'checked' the condition. Thanks so much for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the expression

```
cin >> num1
```

is both operative and expressive. The >> function stores input in **num1** while at the same time returning a boolean value. On a successful read/store cin >> num1 returns **0** and the while loop conditional looks like this:

```
while(!(0)){ //code   }
```

equivalent to

```
while(1){ //code   }
```

equivalent to

```
while(true){ //code   }
```

therefore when cin >> sum1 runs successfully the loop continues.

a failed read/store from cin >> num1 returns I believe **1**, which evaluates to false in the while loop condition.

```
while(!(1)){ //code    }
```

equivalent to

```
while(false){ //code    }
```

and the loop ends here